# Выделение всех checkbox из каждой формы jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выделить все `checkbox` по `id` главного `checkbox`?

Потому, что в `form2` созданы `checkbox` явно, и проблем нет выделения всех чекбоксов.

А вот в другой форме `form1` при нажатии на кнопку появляются чекбоксы.
И с помощью главной кнопки выделения все чексбоксов эта кнопка не выделяет, хоть всё находится в одной `form1`

Comment: если хотите получить рабочий код, а не теоретический совет, то предоставьте свой код, с которым у вас проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  // Создаём динамически боксы во второй форме
  $('#fillForm').on('click', function(e){
    let data = "<input type='text' /><input type='checkbox' /><input type='checkbox' /><input type='password' /><input type='checkbox' /><input type='text' />";
    $('#form2').append(data);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
  
  $('.master').on('change', function(e){
    // Находим все checkbox и ставим им состояние главного переключателя
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Примера кода нет, создам свой для демонстрации -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>Form #1</legend>
  <form id='form1'>
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='text' />
  </form>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Form #2</legend>
  <form id='form2'>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<input type='button' id='fillForm' value='Заполнить вторую форму' />
<label>
  <input type='checkbox' class='master' />Выделить всё
</label>
```

Comment: Что то не работает :( вы сами проверяли? :)

Comment: @Ilenya, конечно, кто выложит решение без теста? Всё работает, вероятно у Вас браузер старый, а код для относительно новых гляделок.

Comment: Вообщем спасибо вам большое проблему я решил дописав класс и обращаясь к созванному классу, а к сожалению ваш пример не смог запустить

Comment: @Ilenya, главное что заработало.